# Socket.io websockets disconnecting randomly

Tags: nginx, websocket, socket.io

I have a socketio server behind an nginx 1.4.2 proxy. When connecting via the browser, the websocket connection disconnects randomly - sometimes after 1 minute, sometimes after 10 minutes. There is no data being transferred during this 1 - 10 minute period that the socket disconnects in. The `proxy_read_timeout` of my nginx config is a liberal 1 day. It happens on both Chrome and Firefox. Here is my nginx configuration for the websocket server block:

```
location / {
  proxy_pass http://socketio_app;
  proxy_redirect off;

  proxy_buffering off;

  proxy_http_version 1.1;
  proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
  proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_read_timeout 86400;
}
```

Comment: Did a bunch of things together - don't know what fixed it. (1) Switched from nginx to haproxy (2) Moved from Socket.io to SockJS (3) Started using primusjs instead of SockJS directly.

Comment: I am in the process of moving away from Socket.IO to Primus and SockJS too. I hope it is a SocketIO thing :)

Comment: One benefit of moving to haproxy, whether or not it fixed the issue for us, was that it allowed us to scale. If you want to load balance websockets, you need to make sure that a particular client is always connected to the same box. Free nginx doesn't allow that kind of load balancing, haproxy does.

Comment: Yes I am aware of that.. For the time being I am relying on the cluster NodeJS to scale websockets and use Redis pubsub for communication between the nodes.